Anime with a pirate protagonist who has blue hair and a scimitar
The protagonist is a pirate and he dresses up kinda like Aladdin with the whole open vest and pants that look like they have balls in them. I remember there was one arc with a bunch of bird people who threw the MC into a canyon and then later he made the queen fall in love with him but I don't remember much else other than:

he has long blue hair

he has a scimitar

he conquers towers and gets magic powers from them


I have already looked for him and I can't find him.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's harder to identify specific characters than the work they appear in; if you want to provide more information about the anime as a whole then you might have a better chance of getting an answer.

he is a pirate and he dresses up kinda like Aladdin with the whole open vest and pants that look like they have balls in them. I remember there was one arc with a bunch of bird people who threw the mc into a canyon and then later he made the queen fall in love with him but I don't remember much else

Could this be Magi: The Labyrinth of Magic or Magi:Adventure of Sinbad?


Fourteen years ago, a structure appeared from the sea, turning into a gigantic tower. Thousands of people entered, and did not come out. Until one day, it gets conquered by two special people, a "Magi" and a "King".
Magi centers around Alibaba Saluja (a young man aiming to capture the nearby dungeon, Amon) and Aladdin (a traveler with a Djinn named Ugo in his flute). Witnessing the power of Aladdin's Djinn, Alibaba finds an opportunity to go dungeon diving with him. Aladdin and Alibaba eventually become friends, and conquer Amon together, despite facing Jamil and his slaves, Morgiana and Goltas. After a desperate fight, Aladdin and Alibaba assist Morgiana in breaking the mental chains that bind her to Jamil. Alibaba claims the dungeon while the Djinn Amon appears to briefly explain that Aladdin is a Magi and Alibaba is his king's candidate. However, they are interrupted by an outside force trying to close the dungeon off. Alibaba, Aladdin, and Morgiana escape the dungeon while Goltas resolves to die to atone for his sins along with Jamil, but not before cutting Morgiana's shackles. Aladdin ends up sent to a distant land, far from the others, where he learns he is a Magi. Having no news of his friend, Alibaba uses the treasure he obtained in Amon to free all slaves in the city, including Morgiana and returns to Balbadd, his homeland.


@whoishe: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].
